# ¿Cómo mostrar un único resultado con botones en AJAX? (ASP.NET)

Tags: ajax, sql-server, asp.net

Estoy haciendo que una lista de temas que mando a traer por medio de procedimientos almacenados se muestre dinámicamente con botones desde un *.js* con *AJAX*.

Ya me enlista todos los temas que existen dependiendo del código del área el cual se elija. Lo que necesito ahora es que para los exámenes que ya se han realizado, muestre el resultado obtenido de dicho estudiante (con un código de sesión se sabe qué estudiante es) y que deshabilite dicho botón. De lo contrario sigan habilitados y sólamente muestre el nombre del tema a examinarse.

Éste es el procedimiento almacenado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Éste es el método de conexión hacia la base de datos que incluye los parámetros:

```
public List<Tema2> ListarAreaTema(String codArea, String codEst)
        {
            List<Tema2> Lista = new List<Tema2>();
            SqlConnection con = null;
            SqlCommand cmd = null;
            SqlDataReader dr = null;
            try
            {
                con = Conexion.getInstance().ConexionBD();
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("spListarAreaTema", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@prmIDArea", codArea);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@prmIDEst", codEst);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    //Creando objetos de Tema
                    Tema2 objTema = new Tema2();
                    objTema.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["cod_tema"].ToString());
                    objTema.ID2 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["cod_area"].ToString());
                    objTema.Nombre = dr["nombre"].ToString();
                    objTema.Descripcion = dr["descripcion"].ToString();
                    objTema.NoPreguntas = Convert.ToInt32(dr["no_preguntas"].ToString());
                    if (dr["cod_estudiante"].ToString() != "") {
                        objTema.IDEst = Convert.ToInt32(dr["cod_estudiante"].ToString());
                    }

                    if (dr["resultado"].ToString() != "") {
                        objTema.Res = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["resultado"].ToString());
                    }

                    //Añadiendo a la lista de objetos
                    Lista.Add(objTema);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            return Lista;
        }
```

Aquí mando a llamar dicho método:

```
[WebMethod]
        public static List<Tema2> ListarAreaTema(String codArea)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["codArea"] = "";
            HttpContext.Current.Session["codArea"] = codArea;
            String codEst = HttpContext.Current.Session["cod_estudiante"].ToString();
            List<Tema2> Lista = null;
            try
            {
                Lista = AreaDAO.getInstance().ListarAreaTema(codArea, codEst);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Lista = null;
            }
            return Lista;
        }
```

Para después mandarlo a llamar desde el *.js* y enlistar los datos por medio de botones dinámicos:

```
function cargarTema(codArea) {
    var obj = JSON.stringify({
        codArea: codArea
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Examen.aspx/ListarAreaTema",
        data: obj,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            (xhr.status + " \n" + xhr.responseText, "\n" + thrownError);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var c = data.d;
            var htmlC = "";
            for (var n = 0; n < c.length; n++) {
                htmlC += '<a href="#" onclick="cargarExamen(' + c[n].ID + ')" class="btn btn-info btn-block" role="button">'
                    + c[n].Nombre + '</a><br>';
            }
            $('.lstAreas').css("display", "none");
            $('.lstTema').css("display", "inline");
            $('#cntTema').html(htmlC);
        }
    });
}
```

Cualquier información que haga falta, hacérmelo saber y yo la añado a la pregunta. Espero por favor puedan ayudarme.

Comment: El parámetro "m.resultado", si no se ha evaluado ese tema, que te retorna?

Comment: Retorna un valor nulo.

Comment: @OscarAnibal no le agregues solucionado al título, acepta la respuesta que te resolvió el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución, la dejo acá por si alguien está buscando también una solución similar.

Modifiqué el código del *.js* añadiéndole un `if(){}else{}` e incluyendo el resultado dentro del botón. Ésto fue lo que añadí:

```
if (c[n].Res == null) {
                    htmlC += '<a href="#" onclick="cargarExamen(' + c[n].ID + ')" class="btn btn-info btn-block" role="button">'
                        + c[n].Nombre + '</a><br>';
                }
                else {
                    htmlC += '<a href="#" onclick="cargarTema(' + c[n].ID + ')" class="btn btn-success btn-block" role="button" disabled="true">'
                    + c[n].Nombre + ' ' + '-' + ' ' + 'Resultado:' + ' ' + c[n].Res + '/100' + '</a><br>';
                }
```

Y quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
function cargarTema(codArea) {
    var obj = JSON.stringify({
        codArea: codArea
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Examen.aspx/ListarAreaTema",
        data: obj,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            (xhr.status + " \n" + xhr.responseText, "\n" + thrownError);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var c = data.d;
            var htmlC = "";
            for (var n = 0; n < c.length; n++) {
                if (c[n].Res == null) {
                    htmlC += '<a href="#" onclick="cargarExamen(' + c[n].ID + ')" class="btn btn-info btn-block" role="button">'
                        + c[n].Nombre + '</a><br>';
                }
                else {
                    htmlC += '<a href="#" onclick="cargarTema(' + c[n].ID + ')" class="btn btn-success btn-block" role="button" disabled="true">'
                    + c[n].Nombre + ' ' + '-' + ' ' + 'Resultado:' + ' ' + c[n].Res + '/100' + '</a><br>';
                }
            }
            $('.lstAreas').css("display", "none");
            $('.lstTema').css("display", "inline");
            $('#cntTema').html(htmlC);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Creo que mi pregunta te ayudo a solucionarlo de alguna manera, me da gusto, un saludo.